# Netbeans - How do I hide the vertical bar w/colors?

Tags: netbeans, interface

Haven't found an option in the IDE to hide it, are there any configuration files that would do it? I never use it, and in my effort to optimize screen space with multiple tab groups, this would save me some pixels. :-P

Here's the bar in question:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/inwUM.png

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are referring to the Diff Sidebar. To remove this use the menu item located at View > Show Diff Sidebar. This menu item is a toggled menu item so when it is active there is a check beside it.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, I could have sworn I went through all the "View" options.

Problem is, unchecking the diff bar doesn't hide the vertical bar, it only hides the colors. The space the vertical bar occupies is what I need to hide. =(

Edit - I think the checkbox for "Diff bar" also only shows up if you're using Version Control, which I'm not.

Comment: Just to add to that - the diff bar is actually really a vertical area near the line numbers, and toggling the diff bar removes that area, but also turns off the line colors in the vertical bar to the right.